# Find the inverse of the function: $f(x)=x^9+x$

Tags: functions, inverse

Let $f(x)=x^9+x$. Show that $f$ has an inverse and find the inverse.

I don't seem to be able to find a way to start tackling this equation. Appreciate any tips on this question.

Comment: Too many questions begin or end with "I don't even know how to begin with this problem". While this may be true [...], it is still not a valid reason to limit your post to the statement of the problem without any mention of your own thoughts.  – From [Avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933/42969).

Comment: "Find the inverse" and "Show it has an inverse" are not the same problem!

Comment: Thanks for the comments. As a new user, i'll take note and many thanks for the patience.

Comment: What do you mean by "find the inverse"? Is this really a part of the problem? This was not present initially in the body of question.

Answer (score 2):

$$f'(x)=9x^8+1>0$$
for all $x$. Therefore it's strictly increasing and thus injective. Moreover, $$\lim_{x\to \infty }f(x)=+\infty \quad \text{and}\quad \lim_{x\to -\infty }f(x)=-\infty .$$

Therefore $f(\mathbb R)=\mathbb R$ by Intermediate value theorem, and thus it's surjective. Therefore it's bijective.

Comment: Derivative is $9x^8+1$.

Comment: @Ramit: thanks.